# How to use the contents of a file as a number

Tags: input

I want to create a loop including n images.The number n is the only content of a help file (created by the application that generates the images).
Is it possible to read the contents of the help file and use that as a number variable to set the loop?

The following code works:

```
\def\cnt{\input{numberfile}}
\cnt
```

Output is the number (i.e. the content of the file).

The following code doesn't work:

```
\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{\input{numberfile}}
\arabic{cnt}
```

The error indicates that the input isn't a number ("Missing number, treated as zero").

So how can I convert the input file to a LaTeX number?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Hi back :-) As I'm still quite new to LaTeX, I'll be only receiving for some time. But in the past I usually turned to answering questions too at some point ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way is to use `\read` which reads a file a line at a time

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcounter{cnt}
\newread\myread 
\openin\myread=numberfile



\begin{document}

\read \myread to \zz

\setcounter{cnt}{\zz}
\arabic{cnt}

\end{document}
```

assuming `numberfile.tex` looks like

```
33
```

Answer (score 11):

Without a `\read`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\setcounterfromfile}[2]{% #1 = counter, #2 = file name
  \CatchFileDef{\scfftemp}{#2}{\endlinechar=-1 }%
  \setcounter{#1}{\scfftemp}}

\newcounter{cnt}

\setcounterfromfile{cnt}{numberfile}

\showthe\value{cnt}
```

If `numberfile.tex` contains the only line `12345` (a very difficult number to guess, as it's well known<sup>1</sup>) we get

```
> 12345.
```

<sup>1</sup> The reference is, of course, to Mel Brooks' *Space Balls*.

Comment: Correction to my comment on the other solution: My real task expects the file name to be passed as an argument, and the file name **may** contain special characters and **does** contain an additional dot. The \read solution doesn't work with that but the 'catchfile' approach does handle such filename without problems.